# How come my question got so many downvotes after answering it myself?

Tags: support, down-votes, self-answer

The question I'm hoping to discuss is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616660/what-is-the-correct-mysql-date-format (10k only)

As a European I'm always doubting if I should use the American date notation or not for MySQL, since I couldn't find a specific question on stackoverflow for it I decided it ask it and answer the question myself. However I received a lot of downvotes by which I was quite shocked.

Can anyone help me understand what I did wrong?

Comment: It looks to me like the comments on the question told you about the issues with it

Comment: The comments told learnt me that: "The question isn't good", "It's a duplicate". Since I couldn't find the original question, does it still make it a duplicate, seems nice to have a question to be found easily.

Comment: I mainly wanted to "ask" the question for my own reference so I could look back to it, but now the question is deleted and is nowhere to be found on my profile, so kind of missed the whole purpose of the question.

Answer (score 12):

The question was a bit sparse.

We like meat in our questions. Give us something we can work with. Here's [one example of my own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291455/xml-data-at-root-level-is-invalid).

Show us what you've tried, give us some context, and paint us a picture of what's going on. Something you said in this post would have been relevant in your question, to wit:

> As a European I'm always doubting if I should use the American date notion or not for MySQL

That's context. That helps us see where you're coming from, and it exhibits an actual problem.

Also, it was a duplicate. I don't think that's a reason to downvote a post, but if you combine it with a pretty sparse post, anything can happen.

It was also a very basic question.  You did try a google search for it, right? [What did that turn up](http://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=mysql+correct+date+format&oq=MySQL+correct+date&gs_l=hp.3.0.0.746.3521.0.4281.20.18.1.0.0.0.115.1233.14j4.18.0.epsugrcchhmlt..0.0...1.1.14.psy-ab.hMg6fWb98v8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.dmg&fp=760e7dfcd4611cfa&biw=1253&bih=680)?

Finally, there is a segment of the community that doesn't like self-answered questions.  It's a minority, but it's there.

Work on improving what you put into your question. If you write the question well, you shouldn't see too many down votes, self-answered or not.

Comment: Oh good point; the note about wondering about the localized issues would have made for an interesting detail there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll be sure to take note of it next time I risk self-answering my questions.

Comment: @user2019515 If you do it well by putting lots of effort into both (and definitely checking the internet to make sure the problem hasn't already been solved on Stack Overflow), you shouldn't get many downvotes at all (if any). The community rewards effort in your posts.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is:

> What is the correct MySQL date/time format? What would be the best way to get this format of the current time in PHP?

The first half doesn't make a lot of sense. The correct date/time format is whatever one that you need. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` is no more *correct* than `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Once the first half of the question is clarified, the second half is extremely Google-able.  There are thousands of questions on Stack Overflow alone that explain how to format dates.  This one didn't need to be posted.

Comment: Are you saying that you can insert any date format in MySQL? So I could easily have chosen for my own date format? `DD-MM-YYYY`

Comment: @user2019515 No, I'm saying that you didn't make clear at all what you were using the date format for.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, asking for "the best" of something is inviting your question to be seen as a "shopping question." Your post should, to the best of your ability, have **an** answer, and not several that could be each be regarded as equally valid (this is a rule of thumb, not an absolute).

If everyone who answers your question could have an equally valid answer, or there could be an extended discussion about which answer is the "most correct", that's a good sign that your question is too vague or open-ended.

Even though you answered it yourself, people will still see the question and vote it on its own merit, rather than your intention.